# Docker-compose in a VM (Parallels) on a M1 mac

Tags: docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04, apple-m1

currently I'm trying to get docker-compose running in my VM (Ubuntu 20.04) on my mac with the M1 processor. I already installed docker and docker machine via curl on my VM. Docker-compose I try to install as follows:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

The installation seems to work out but if I try to check the version via "sudo docker-compose --version", it says: "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: 1: Not: not found".

In ubuntu it say it is an aarch64 due to my M1.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do `chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` for it to be executable by it's owner only, readable by everyone else. `chown root /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` will make it's owner root (so you can only run it with sudo).

`/usr/local/bin` also might not be in your path. Check this by typing `echo $PATH`. If it's not in there, you can either symlink docker-compose to a recognized path (`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose`) or doing `export $PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` to add it to your path. It should then show up if you do `which docker-compose` (shows the path to the program).

Comment: I tried as you suggested. /usr/local/bin wasn't part of the path so thanks for this! Unfortunately, "docker-compose --version" still throws "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: 1: Not: not found
". I tried to download it again via curl and Ubuntu pops up an error now, saying: "System program problem detected". "sudo which docker-compose" says it is in /usr/local/bin/docker-compose". I appreciate your detailed instructions.

Comment: It probably won't let you overwrite an executable binary like that :) you don't need sudo to use docker compose by the way. But I think you should put your user in the docker group if I remember correctly

Answer (score 1):

You see "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: 1: Not: not found" because that is the content of the file - curl received 404 response and wrote the status message to the target file.
There are a couple of options of installing docker-compose on arm64 ubuntu:

1. Using python:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y python3-pip libffi-dev
sudo pip3 install docker-compose
```

2. Installing beta v2 docker-compose beta (on mac or linux):

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/releases/download/v2.0.0-beta.3/docker-compose-`uname -s`-arm64 -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Or download it manually from https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.3.
The API of that tool will be different.

You can also track this discussion for proper resolution - https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6831.